# Server Error in '/' Application. No printers are installed

Tags: c#, asp.net

Server Error in '/' Application.

No printers are installed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException: No printers are installed.

Source Error:

```
Line 166:              
Line 167:               
Line 168:                    rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
Line 169:              
Line 170:                //Response.Redirect("~/SavingsAccountReg.aspx");
```

Source File: `d:\inetpub\vhosts\atmnidhi.com\httpdocs\savingreport.aspx.cs`    Line: 168

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidPrinterException: No printers are installed.]
   System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmodeInternal(String printer) +199408
   System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmodeInternal() +28
   System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmode(PageSettings pageSettings) +48
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.PrintOptions.CopyTo(PrinterSettings printer, PageSettings page) +322
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.PrintToPrinter(Int32 nCopies, Boolean collated, Int32 startPageN, Int32 endPageN) +176
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(Int32 nCopies, Boolean collated, Int32 startPageN, Int32 endPageN) +73
   savingreport.btnsave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\inetpub\vhosts\atmnidhi.com\httpdocs\savingreport.aspx.cs:168
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9633962
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237

No printers are installed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException: No printers are
>   installed.

Comment: how to solve this error

Answer (score 1):

> how to solve this error

Assuming you actually intend to allow a web request to cause a printer connected to the *server* to print something out

1. Make sure there is a default printer configured for the server
2. Make sure the identity under which the web application is running has permission to access the printer.

Note that if a hacker gained access to this web page, they could cause you to go through quite a bit of paper and ink/toner :-)

Comment: but crystal report viewer is not support in my application .but working well in local system ? so how can i solve this issues ?